# How to iterate over a table?

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a table in the following structure:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td> Name: </td>
     <td> Juan </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> Name: </td>
     <td> Alex </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

I want to iterate through the second `td` in the `tr` and grab the name (Juan, Alex) 
I wrote the following code to do it:

```
   driver.find_elements(:xpath => "//table/tbody/tr/td[2]").each do |r|
            puts  r.text
    end
```

It doesn't produce any errors, no `unable to find element`. anything. It just skips over these lines of code. It's not printing out any blanks either. I put a test for it inside the do loop and did not reach in there. I know the xpath is correct, I checked in firebug. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hope this helps - http://elementalselenium.com/tips/25-tables

Comment: Are you sure `find_elements` will raise an error when nothing is found, not an empty array? I'd double check your xpath.

Answer (score -1):

You can traverse the WebTable easily using for loops on Table Data and Table Row's XPaths. See the Sample program -

```
public class WebTable {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void openWebSite() {

        // Open Raddif Gainer page
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://money.rediff.com/gainers/bse/daily/groupa?src=gain_lose");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void CountRowsTest() {

        // Store all rows in the List
        List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr"));

        // To get the all present rows in the Table
        System.out.println("Totoal rows are -- " + allRows.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void printallrowsTest() {

        // Store all rows in the List
        List<WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr"));

        // To Print the whole content of the table
        for (int i = 0; i < allRows.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(allRows.get(i).getText());
        }
 }
```

For more details, you can refer this amazing tutorial:

http://www.seleniumbix.com/#!handle-webtables-in-selenium/c329

Comment: The OP wanted it in ruby.You have posted in java

Comment: Translating to Ruby should be easily possible with the complexity of the posted code.